# Predicting multiple test sets with Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have a training set and a testing set which I want to classify with Weka. and because my attribute is a text .. I understand that I have to apply first the stringtoword filter first. As has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439157/predicting-text-data-labels-in-test-data-set-with-weka), I have to do the following: 
1- load the train and test sets and apply the filter.
2- Train the classifier using the training set and save the model.
3- Load the model to apply it on the testing set.

I my experiment I have to use the trained classifier to test multiple test sets .. so, do I have to repeat 1,2 and 3 or I can repeat the third step only ?

and do I have to replace the class in testing set with a question mark (?) or I can leave the class their and the classifier will try to predict the class anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply repeat the third step assuming all the testing sets have been filtered and saved with the filtered version. If you select the 'More options...' button and check the output predictions box then you do not have to replace the class with a question mark.

Comment: I am very sorry but I still didn't get it :( .. when you say "assuming all the testing sets have been filtered and saved with the filtered version" do you mean that I have to apply the filter on 'step one' on all the testing sets and then classify them one by one ? because I have testing sets which are data grouped by year which I don't want to mix together and I want to classify them using the same trained classifier and I am not sure how to do that! do I have to repeat the whole experiment for each testing set .. or I just have to repeat the last step.

Comment: Should just be the last step. Filter your data and save the filtered version to an .arff file and use it in step 3.

Comment: But I don't think I can do the following with my multiple test files: test1, test2, test3 ... testn   :    (    java -Xmx1024m weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector 
           –b -i training.arff -o Output_training.arff -r test1.arff test2.arff test3.arff –s output_test1.arff output_test2.arff output_test3.arff
           -R 2 -W 5000 -C -T -I -N 1 -L -M 2  )   since I want to convert multiple test files instead of putting them in one large test file.